# ClassCastException when reading entities with Jersey client

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS resource that returns an object of type `A`. I use JAXB for serialization into XML. The server works fine and I am able to retrieve the correct XML as string.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><a><x>xA</x>/a>`

The problem shows when I use Jersey test client to read the server-generated object. In fact, to de-serialize XML I use a subclass `B` of the original class `A` used to serialize, that has extra setters (to be able to capture those properties). However, I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` with a message like `test.AppTest$A cannot be cast to test.AppTest$B`.

My question is how does Jersey client or JAXB know about the type of the serialized object at the server side (that is `A`) even though no type information was serialized?

My understanding is that JAX-RS implementation (Jersey in this case) will try to de-serialize the XML content using `B`, and is agnostic as to the type used for serialization. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is a minimally working example.

```
package test;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("/")
public class AppTest extends JerseyTest {

    public AppTest() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(AppTest.class);
    }

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public A get() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Test
    public void testApp() {
        B b = this.target().request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
            .get().readEntity(B.class);
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class A {
        public A() {}

        @XmlElement
        public String getX() { return "xA";}
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class B extends A {
        public B() {}

        public void setX(String value) {}
    }
}
```

Besides JUnit 4.12, the example only directly depends on the following artifact: `org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2:2.25.1`. I tried different flavors (in memory, jetty) to the same observation.

If I retrieve `b` as `Object`, things work fine, but `b`'s type is `A`.

```
@Test
public void testApp() {
    Object b = this.target().request()
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
        .get().readEntity(B.class);
    System.out.println(b.getClass()); # class test.AppTest$A
}
```

Thanks for any insights.